# Robot Model Drifing in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-noetic

I am trying to simulate a robot in gazebo, however when I monitored closely I saw that the robot is very slowly drifting. Then I tried it with already available different robot like turtelbot , clearpath husky , everyone of them is drifting same as my robot was.

Gazebo Version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.13.0 Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation. Released under the Apache 2 License. http://gazebosim.org

I wanted to know why every robot I spawn in my gazebo is drifting? Initally I thought it’s because of inertia of my robot but other model like turtule bot is showing same behaviour! I trued reinstalling gazebo also but didn’t work.

Comment: You have not asked a question. Please edit your post.

Comment: Did you create a virtual joint in your URDF model to fix the robot base?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ankit Kumar, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to **include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see.** Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: How are you spawning the robot? How are you detecting drift? Did you follow any tutorials? As it stands, there's not enough information to provide meaningful feedback.

Comment: I cloned the github https://github.com/sulibo/two_wheeled_robot_ROS_tutorial and tried to run the  spawn.launch , when I zoomed into the robot too close , I see that the robot is moving very slowly. I usually will leave my mouse on edge and after few minutes you can see the robot is moved.

Comment: What scale of movement/velocity are you seeing? In general the simulation is using numerical solvers and the robots with hard edges and surfaces can have small jitter in the solution which causes slow drift as there's not correction force to push things back. Tuning the model and environment to make sure there's enough damping and to avoid high mass ratios will help.

Comment: The motion is very very slow , only after zooming in very much we can see the drifting towards ant side, ever this is happening with the turtulebot, so I am thinking the problem might be in environment. But I installed gazebo for the first time freshly.

Comment: @Ankit-Kumar - most people see this behavior in their gazebo simulations. It is not a problem with your specific environment.